# git через прокси

Tags: git, proxy

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь стянуть проект с работы на домашний комп. Сказали делать это через vpn. Но чтобы с vpn не заморачиваться, пытаюсь с помощью tor получить доступ к git. На хабре нашел статью, где один из способов это указывание прокси в конфигурации гита.

```
$ git config --global http.proxy socks5://localhost:9150
$ git config --global https.proxy socks5://localhost:9150
```

А затем клонирование

```
$ git clone https://192.168.1.8/myproject
```

Но у меня это дело не выходит, выдает следующую ошибку

```
can't complete socks5 connection to 0.0.0.0
```

Что я не так делаю? Может, кто-то знает другой способ настройки?

Comment: А кто сказал, что без VPN вообще будет доступ? Ещё у вас очень странный IP для рабочего гита

Comment: Может быть потому что на работе все клонируется/коммитится/пушится? На рабочем компе доступ к гиту получаю так git://192.168.1.8/myproject

Comment: Вот у меня тут рядом лежит ноутбук у которого IP 192.168.1.8, но это не значит, что на нём ваш проект лежит.

Comment: Чтобы подсоединяться к Tor-прокси, надо этот прокси сначала поднять. Вы это сделали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас задача получить доступ к VPN, вам не поможет tor. Вам не запретили обращение с вашего IP-адреса, вас не пускают внутрь сети. Вам не новый IP-адрес нужен, а ключи/генератор кодов VPN. Без штатного подключения к VPN, вам не добраться до проекта из недоверенной сети.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.